# Breaking login flow if already logged in with another session

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am working on a codeigniter 3 app and ive recently implemented a session checker that deletes a user session if they're already logged in. Now we want a modal box to pop up if the user is already logged in with another session. I am able to get a modal box to pop up using a button but i want to implement it into the original flow of the login system.  As it is the login form takes you straight to the validate login system. This is the login form now:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('login/validate_login/user'); ?>" method="post">
  <div class="content-box">
      <div class="basic-group">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="login-email"><span class="input-field-icon"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span> <?php echo get_phrase('email'); ?>:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name = "email" id="login-email" placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('email'); ?>" value="" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="login-password"><span class="input-field-icon"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span> <?php echo get_phrase('password'); ?>:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name = "password" placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('password'); ?>" value="" required>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-update-box">
      <button type="submit" class="btn"><?php echo get_phrase('login'); ?></button>
  </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">                                
          <h4 class="modal-title">You are already logged in</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>You are currently logged in on a different session on the site. Please note that if you continue, the existing session will be terminated. Please change your password if you suspect that your account has been conpromised.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel Login</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn"><?php echo get_phrase('login'); ?></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="forgot-pass text-center">
      <span><?php echo get_phrase('or'); ?></span>
      <a href="javascript::" onclick="toggoleForm('forgot_password')"><?php echo get_phrase('forgot_password'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <div class="account-have text-center">
      <?php echo get_phrase('do_not_have_an_account'); ?>? <a href="javascript::" onclick="toggoleForm('registration')"><?php echo get_phrase('sign_up'); ?></a>
  </div>
</form>
```

The button at the moment goes straight to this login function:

```
    public function validate_login($from = "") {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $credential = array('email' => $email, 'password' => sha1($password), 'status' => 1);

        // Checking login credential for admin
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', $credential);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $row->id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('role_id', $row->role_id);
            $this->session->set_userdata('role', get_user_role('user_role', $row->id));
            $this->session->set_userdata('name', $row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name);
            $this->delete_session_user_id();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('welcome').' '.$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name);
            if ($row->role_id == 1) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('admin_login', '1');
                redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
            }else if($row->role_id == 2){
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_login', '1');
                $this->set_session_user_id();
                redirect(site_url('home/my_courses'), 'refresh');
            }
        }else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message',get_phrase('invalid_login_credentials'));
            redirect(site_url('home/login'), 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

I created this function to pull the user id from the emails:

```
    public function get_user_id($user_email = "") {
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->where('email', $user_email);
        $user_id=$this->db->get('users');
        return $user_id;
    }
```

This function can get the user id based on the email supplied.

Then I use this function to check if there is a session and return *false* if there are 0 results and *true* if there is a session with that user id. So if its false they should be able to log in and the modal pop-up shouldnt open but if its true it should open.

```
    public function user_has_session($user_id=''){
        $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
        $this->db->from('ci_sessions');
        $total=$this->db->count_all_results();
        if($total<0) 
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

I think this is the best approach without having to redo the entire login flow. Perhaps someone can advise if this is the best approach or if in fact i should change the entire flow.

Thanks

Here is the previous problem I had which I have answered myself
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458226/codeigniter-3-stop-multiple-logins-using-ci-sessions-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458226/codeigniter-3-stop-multiple-logins-using-ci-sessions-database.)

**UPDATE Added to clarify my problem**

Well the problem is when a login is attempted from another device it should logout the other active session. So if o logged in on my desktop in a new browser or even my phone with the same user ID the active session should end, at the moment it does so without warning the user. So I want to have a modal pop up warning the user that there is an active session currently running with this user id

Comment: this is a bit unclear: *implemented session checker that deletes a user session if they're already logged in*: why do you want to do that? if user is logged-in (session is alive), just make a logout function available and hide the login part. problem resolved.

Comment: Well the problem is when a login is attempted from another device it should logout the other active session. So if o logged in on my desktop in a new browser or even my phone with the same user ID the active session should end, at the moment it does so without warning the user. So I want to have a modal pop up warning the user that there is an active session currently running with this user id. Am I making sense? Am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: now I understood, please edit your last comment into the question and try to reduce your code to **essential** to show your problem, so all users can understand better. Anyway, I think the easiest way would be to check periodically on client side (javascript), if the original session is still going, otherwise show pop_up (this to show the message on original device if no user action has occurred there, if there is user-action, you catch it there)

Comment: Ahhh I think I can do that with a session Ajax call of some sort

Comment: Better use WebSockets. Use something like this http://socketo.me/. Or maybe something like https://reactphp.org/http/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement an Ajax call which will check whether the user is already logged in or not. If the user is not logged In than you can proceed to login otherwise trigger your popup open to display the message.

Here the user has choices to log in or not, If users choose to login then you can unbind the event on submit and let the user go ahead.

I have made some changes to your HTML file. Please check below -

**Your HTML template**

```
      <form action="<?php echo site_url('login/validate_login/user'); ?>" id="login-form" onSubmit="return checkUserSession();" method="post">
        <div class="content-box">
            <div class="basic-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="login-email"><span class="input-field-icon"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span> <?php echo get_phrase('email'); ?>:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name = "email" id="login-email" placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('email'); ?>" value="" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="login-password"><span class="input-field-icon"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span> <?php echo get_phrase('password'); ?>:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name = "password" placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('password'); ?>" value="" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-update-box">
            <button type="submit" class="btn"><?php echo get_phrase('login'); ?></button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">                                
                <h4 class="modal-title">You are already logged in</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You are currently logged in on a different session on the site. Please note that if you continue, the existing session will be terminated. Please change your password if you suspect that your account has been conpromised.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel Login</button>
                <button type="button" id="modal-submit-button" class="btn"><?php echo get_phrase('login'); ?></button>
            </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="forgot-pass text-center">
            <span><?php echo get_phrase('or'); ?></span>
            <a href="javascript::" onclick="toggoleForm('forgot_password')"><?php echo get_phrase('forgot_password'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="account-have text-center">
            <?php echo get_phrase('do_not_have_an_account'); ?>? <a href="javascript::" onclick="toggoleForm('registration')"><?php echo get_phrase('sign_up'); ?></a>
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <script>
        /** Trigger function on form submit whether to check user logged in */
        function checkUserSession(){
            var email = $("#login-email").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('login/checkUserSession'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'email': email},                               
                success: function(status){                 
                    if(status == true) { // User is already logged in somewhere, display the messege.
                        $("#login").modal();
                        return false;
                    } else { // User is not logged in, submit the form
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        
        /** Allow user to log in with exception */
        $("#modal-submit-button").on("click", function(){
            $("#login").modal('hide'); // hide the modal
            $("#login-form").attr("onSubmit", ""); // unbind the function
            $("#login-form").submit(); // submit login form
        })
    </script>
```

**Controller** -

```
   <?php

       /** Function to check user logged in or not */
        public function checkUserSession() {
            $user_email = $this->input->post('email');
            $userId = $this->get_user_id($user_email);
            $response = $this->user_has_session($userId);
            echo $response;
        }

        public function get_user_id($user_email = "") {
            $this->db->select('id');
            $this->db->where('email', $user_email);
            $user_id=$this->db->get('users');
            return $user_id;
        }

        public function user_has_session($user_id=''){
            $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
            $this->db->from('ci_sessions');
            $total=$this->db->count_all_results();
            if($total<0) 
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: Thanks I will try this soon

Comment: So this doesn't seem to be working but this may be because I haven't tested all the functions above fully to see if they return results correctly. Can i send you a DM to my development site link and you can test it there?

Comment: Ok, You need to place all the things. Because they are connected to each other. If you replaced only HTML file then you should see the ajax call in the console/network tab when you submit your form.

Comment: I have placed all the things, im just not sure about the other php functions that I created. Im not sure if those work as expected as I havent tested them fully

Comment: Ok I see now there is an error with the checkUserSession function but it flashes by so quickly I cant see what it is. Ill need to add a break point

Comment: You can see the error in the console or in the network tab. When the Ajax request submitted to the server it shows under the console/network tab. By clicking on that request you will see the whole information. Under preview tab, it will show the response returned by the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216418/discussion-between-zayd-bhyat-and-alok-mali).

Comment: Ultimately this was the best solution for this problem. There was an issue with my queries and query builder but its working as expected now